# A fact about non-homothetic lattices

Tags: manifolds, elliptic-curves

Let $\mathbb H$ be the upper half-plane, and let $\Gamma:=SL_2(\Bbb Z)$. Let $\tau, \tau' \in \mathbb H$ such that $\Gamma\tau \neq \Gamma\tau'$, and let $L:=\mathbb Z \oplus \tau\mathbb Z$ and $L':=\mathbb Z \oplus \tau'\mathbb Z$. Then $L$ and $L'$ are two compact Riemann surfaces. Why they are not $\Bbb C$-analytically isomorphic? Why they are diffeomorphic? (I can check that the action of $SL_2(\Bbb R)$ is transitive, but I can not see why the transitivity of the action of $SL_2(\Bbb R)$, implies they are diffeomorphic.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complex analytic isomorphism $f:\Bbb{C}/L\to \Bbb{C}/L'$ lifts to a complex analytic isomorphism $\Bbb{C\to C}$ thus it has to be of the form $z\to az+b$ ie. $L' = aL$.

Equivalently $dz$ is an holomorphic 1-form on $\Bbb{C}/L$, the other mermorphic 1-forms are $h(z)dz$ with $h$ meromorphic on $\Bbb{C}/L$, thus $h(z)dz$ is an holomorphic 1-form iff $h$ has no poles nor zeros ie. $h$ is constant. $df(z)$ is also an holomorphic 1-form on $\Bbb{C}/L$, thus $df(z)=adz$ for some $a\ne 0$ and hence $L'=aL$.

Comment: Here $a$ and $b$ should belong to $\Bbb Z$? Why we have $b=0$? Also, I can not see why the transitivity of the action of $SL_2(\Bbb R)$ implies that they are diffeomorphic?

Comment: $a,b$ are complex numbers, $a\ne 0$. Thus $L' +c = aL+b$ and $0\in aL+b-c$ gives $(b-c)\in aL$. It is obvious that any two complex tori are diffeomorphic, try the $\Bbb{R}$-linear transformations of $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: @NeoTheComputer If $u = \frac{a\tau +b}{c\tau+d}$ (this time $SL_2(Z)$) then $Z+\tau Z= r (Z+u Z),r= ?$

Comment: I thought about it, but I can not find the answer.